# What happens when the spell Mental Prison ends if a creature reaches through?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

What happens when the spell *mental prison* ends when the creature reaches through?

According to the spell description:

> the target takes 10d10 psychic damage, and the spell ends. (XGtE 161)

Does this mean they can then take their full turn? Or does this complete their turn?

I am thinking of using this spell on an adult dragon during the Rise of Tiamat campaign.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll imprison an adult dragon to begin with. The creature will prefer to spend one of its 3 legendary saves instead of suffering from 10d10 extra damage. And by the time that you cast the spell so many times that the adult dragon failed the throws a fourth time despite its +6 to +9 to charisma saves, it would have already suffered at least 4 times 5d10 initial psychic damage. So with those 10d10 extra damage for breaking the prison... that's a situation with minimum 30d10 psychic damage dealt out of 200-225 hit points: your team will have already likely finished the job.

Comment: The party were going to burn through the legendary saves. Also I am a Sorc I can give the dragon disadvantage on the save and my DC is 17. I like my odds :)

Answer (score 12):

## The target's turn is not ended

Reaching through the illusion created by [*mental prison*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mental-prison) could involve making an attack through the illusion (which, for a creature with Multiattack or Extra Attack, means that they still get to make more attacks after the spell ends), or simply reaching through the illusion with any body part (in which case they'd still have their action, bonus action, movement, unless a DM ruled that reaching through the illusion used up an action or bonus action, but they'd still have movement and either action or bonus action).

> If the target is moved out of the illusion, **makes a melee attack through it, or reaches any part of its body through it**, the target takes 10d10 psychic damage, and the spell ends. (XGtE, p. 161)

Assuming they survive the 10d10 psychic damage, nothing in the spell description says that their turn ends when the spell ends.